# Rspec Controller Name with Underscore - Mapping Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a controller named GkServiceAreaController which is defined in app/controllers/gk_service_area_controller.rb.
The route mapping is

```
get '/:slug', to: 'gk_service_area#index', as: :service_details
```

I have a spec in spec
/controllers/gk_service_area_controller_spec.rb

```
it 'should render' do
    get :index
    expect(assigns(:test)).to eq('asfasfd')
end
```

The app is running ok but RSpec is failing with this error:

```
   ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"gk_service_area"}
```

When I tried to change the route mapping to:

```
get '/:slug', to: 'GkServiceArea#index', as: :service_details
```

Or

```
get '/:slug', to: 'gkServiceArea#index', as: :service_details
```

It will fail with the error: Controller name not supported.

How can i get around with Rspec now?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my original question. The problem is the mapping for this route which looks like following.

```
get '/:slug', to: 'gk_service_area#index', as: :service_details
```

So when I run the test, it has to be

```
it 'should render' do
    get :index, params: { slug: 'abc' }
    expect(assigns(:test)).to eq('asfasfd')
end
```

The difference is {slug: 'abc'}. The problem was not with my controller's name.